En Django 2 Cómo puedo redireccionar de un template a otro pasando un parametro
Buen día, tengo un template llamado tabla.html en el que muestro una tabla, necesito que cada fila constituya un link que apunte hacia otro template llamado detalle_parte.html, donde se recibe el id de la fila seleccionada como parámetro, uso la propiedad onSelectRow de jqgrid para capturar este id, el código en tabla.html es el siguiente:
onSelectRow: function(rowId) {
 var detalleUrl = "{% url 'UFC:detalle_parte' %}?id=" + rowId; 
 window.location.href = detalleUrl;
}

la forma de capturar el dato en la vista es la siguiente:
def detalle_parte(request):
    parte_id = request.GET.get('id') 
    parte = get_object_or_404(UFCParteInformeOperativo, id=parte_id)
    return render(request, 'detalle_parte.html', {'parte': parte,'idd':parte_id})

y en detalle_parte.html tengo el código de ejemplo siguiente:
<html><h1>ID enviado por parametro desde la vista: {{ idd }}</h1></html>

No está haciendo la redirección correctamente. Alguien que me puede ayudar. Saludos cordiales.

Buen dia daril cuando no dices no esta haciendo la redireccion correctamente a que te refieres que error te muestra ? que sale en  consola?

Es facil, solo al meter la url mandas al lado el atributo o parametro, por ejemplo:
{% url 'UFC:detalle_parte' {{detalle.id}} %}

De esta manera cuando mandes a llamar la url se le mandará el parámetro al template detalle_parte.html.
